# Entropy change of system in adiabatic irreversible process

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

In an adiabatic irreversible process we know that q = 0. Now change in entropy is defined as q/T. So when q is zero, why is change in entropy not zero ?

Comment: also: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/10706/entropy-change-in-adiabatic-process?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

The change in entropy is the *reversible* heat flow divided by $T$.  So if the process is irreversible, you can't use the irreversible process's heat flow to find the entropy change.

Comment: So, how do you find entropy change in an adiabatic irreversible process ?

Comment: To find the entropy change in an adiabatic irreversible process, you need to figure out (i.e., identify) a reversible path between the same pair of initial- and final equilibrium states of the system (any reversible path will suffice) and calculate the integral of dq/T for that path.  For more on this, see the following link:  https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/understanding-entropy-2nd-law-thermodynamics/